# Как объединить название столбцов в DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Как объединить название столбцов в DataFrame?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_rows = 10
n_cols = 4
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])


def pir1(df_1, df_2):
    pidx = np.indices((df_1.shape[1], df_2.shape[1])).reshape(2, -1)
    lcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_1.columns, df_2.columns], names=[df_1.columns.name, df_2.columns.name])
    return pd.DataFrame(df_1.values[:, pidx[0]] + df_2.values[:, pidx[1]], columns=lcol)

print(pir1(df_1, df_2))

  col0                col1            ... col2           col3               
  col0 col1 col2 col3 col0 col1 col2  ... col1 col2 col3 col0 col1 col2 col3
0   99   83   64   23  139  123  104  ...  157  138   97  134  118   99   58
1   92   72   54  109   68   48   30  ...   91   73  128  151  131  113  168
2   92   73   92   91  125  106  125  ...   65   84   83   72   53   72   71
3  110  121  133  167   99  110  122  ...  129  141  175   75   86   98  132

[4 rows x 16 columns]
```

Как сделать что бы название столбцов соединялось? вот такой результат на выходе должен получиться:

```
     col0_col0  col0_col1  col0_col2  ...  col3_col1  col3_col2  col3_col3
0         99         83         64    ...       118         99         58
1         92         72         54    ...       131        113        168
2         92         73         92    ...        53         72         71
3        110        121        133    ...        86         98        132
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На вашем примере, можно задать названия колонок через генератор:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_rows = 10
n_cols = 4
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])


def pir1(df_1, df_2):
    pidx = np.indices((df_1.shape[1], df_2.shape[1])).reshape(2, -1)
    cols = [f'{col_1}' + f'_{col_2}' for col_1 in df_1.columns for col_2 in df_2.columns] # названия колонок
    return pd.DataFrame(df_1.values[:, pidx[0]] + df_2.values[:, pidx[1]], columns=cols)

pir1(df_1, df_2)


 col0_col0  col0_col1   col0_col2   
0   135        144         170  
1   93          87          47  
2   79          26          27
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам @Илья Митусов !